# How to develop springboot on local and deploy war on wildfly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly

I'm trying to develop a maven java EE rest application with angular client using spring boot as local development and finally generate a WAR file to be deployed on wildfly.

I found a lot of documentation on how to generate a war package with springboot, but this configuration won't let me keep springboot on local for local development.

How can I keep spring boot for local development while generate a war package to be deployed on wildfly?

Comment: If you can share the issues you are facing currently, I may be able to help a bit more ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you really want to do this, you will have to create two maven profiles, one for local where you add tomcat as dependendency and other where you create a jar.

That being said, I don't think it is wise idea to do so because your development and deployment environment will become different, there is a chance you will encounter issues only when you are deploying on wildfly. JBoss distributions are notorious for preferring their own bundled jars overs yours unless you override it with `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

Comment: So how do you suggest to keep having local development?

Comment: use either jboss or tomcat in both the environments.